# How to limit number of locations for each vehicle in Google OR-Tools Route Optimization

Tags: c#, or-tools

I have implemented Or-Tools for route optimization. Its working fine. Only one thing which i want to achieve that limit number of locations for each vehicle. For example, maximum two(2) locations defined for each vehicle.

I have tried to implement Capacity Constraint but it does not work. Also i tried to implement SetSpanUpperBoundForVehicle function, in this case solution object is null.

Here is my code

```
RoutingDimension timeDimension = routing.GetMutableDimension("Time");
            timeDimension.SetSpanUpperBoundForVehicle(2, 0);
            timeDimension.SetSpanUpperBoundForVehicle(2, 1);
            timeDimension.SetSpanUpperBoundForVehicle(2, 2);
```

How can i limit this number of routes? Please help.

Comment: Each vehicle is only doing 1 route. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: I have 5 routes. By implementing VRPTW solution, 3 routes assigned to vehicle 2 and 1, 1 route assigned to vehicle 0 and 1 respectively. I want to limit number of routes to 2, so no any vehicle can have more than 2 routes.

Comment: By route, you mean visit ?

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake. Actually the locations, i have 5 locations and i want to limit 2 locations for each vehicle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply  create a counter dimension, at each location add 1, then for each vehicle limit the capacity to the number of maximum locations allowed.

e.g. reusing [vrp.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp.py) sample and adding:

```py
   # Create counter
    def counter_callback(from_index):
        """Returns 1 for any locations except depot."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to user NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return 1 if (from_node != 0) else 0;

    counter_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(counter_callback)

    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        counter_callback_index,
        0,  # null slack
        [4,5,4,6],  # maximum locations per vehicle
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Counter')
```

possible output:

```sh
%python vrp.py
Objective: 6780
Route for vehicle 0:
 0 -> 7 -> 0
Distance of the route: 388m

Route for vehicle 1:
 0 -> 14 -> 16 -> 15 -> 3 -> 4 -> 0
Distance of the route: 2716m

Route for vehicle 2:
 0 -> 13 -> 12 -> 11 -> 1 -> 0
Distance of the route: 1804m

Route for vehicle 3:
 0 -> 5 -> 8 -> 6 -> 2 -> 10 -> 9 -> 0
Distance of the route: 1872m

Total Distance of all routes: 6780m
```

As you can see, routes respect the `4, 5, 4, 6` locations limit.

Note: For C# syntax, it is barely the same see
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/VrpCapacity.cs
and https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/VrpCapacity.csproj